# Why does memory usage not going down even after stopping my tensorflow object detection script?

Tags: tensorflow, memory-management, tensorflow2.0, object-detection-api

I am training object detection pipeline which is developed using TensorFlow library. My problem is, even after stopping the script memory usage is really high and not going down. **Can somebody recommend a remedy to this problem?**

I am using **TensorFlow=2.6** and the **object detection API from tensorflow** to train on my data.

Even after I re-ran my script (model_main_tf2) after stopping the older ones, these older ones are still consuming a lot of memory (with same name as model_main_tf2) as can be seen in the figure below.

[image: memory usage]

Answer (score 0):

try running:

```
tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
```

after you are finished running a model

Comment: I had to run the model over the weekend and slowly slowly the RAM consumption increases during this training period and finally the system crashes. Should I use tf.keras.backend.clear_session() while training the model?